# Not getting a embedded code for video

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, curl, file-get-contents

In my project user will upload a video by pasting a URL from another site. I tried embedly but doesn't work properly since it gives embedded code for a particular site, YouTube etc. I want to do exactly like this site http://www.myvidster.com/. I tried using `cURL` code for this:-

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $video_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // Display communication with server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json_reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

and code with `file_get_contents` is:

```
$video_url = $_POST['video_url'];
$html = file_get_contents($video_url,true);
```

But using curl also I got HTML part of some sites only. I am trying for 1 week but still no result. Is it possible to get an embedded code for video from every site? Or I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Short answer: "From every site" - No. "From a bunch of the most popular sites" - Yes, but with separate work for each site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be looking into the [oembed standard](http://oembed.com/)

this protocol allows you to receive the embed code from multiple video sites that support it, in a standard unified way.
Click the link to see a list of sites that implement oembed

http://oembed.com/#section7

For the other websites that don't support this standard you can usually fetch the embed code through the open graph protocol (meta og:...) or write html parsing rules for each site to extract the embed

Answer (score 11):

There is no single, generic way to do this for all video streaming sites -- every site is a bit different, and not all of them have any support for an embedded view.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but if you see this site http://www.myvidster.com/ , they are showing a video from different site. What I want to say is they are getting a embeded code from all site. I want to do exactly like this.

Comment: You're making a big assumption here. It's much more likely that they've written code to figure out the embed code based on the user's input.

Comment: Yeah - my best guess would be that they've done a bunch of work to figure out how to embed videos from all the common video-sharing sites. No easy, short answer here; just a lot of work.

Comment: Do not forget also that many site provide an API : you give this API the video ID, and base on that you can get JSon or XML info on the video. Here is an example of output from vimeo: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/1778399.json With this you'll have title, description, duration... It's not what you want at the moment, but you might want it afterwards.
As for the embedding code, once you have a video ID, usually it is documented in the API as well. But as said above, every site will have its specificities, so adding support for another site will require extra work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try retrieving `og:video` meta tag, make sure that `og:video:type` meta tag is `application/x-shockwave-flash`

Then you can embed it easily. Though there is no completely automatic method, sometimes you will need to implement specific ways for specific websites since not all video websites share the same "STANDARD".

Answer (score 0):

You need to reencode the videos to be sure that they will be viewed in a brower. A great command line software for that is [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). The best is, it is free!

Comment: valid but not in the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing to deal with for my site [www.youtubetutsite.com](http://www.youtubetutsite.com/). Though I only used YouTube.

From looking at myvidster.com, They do not play all videos. The one's that they cant play, they have a screenshot that acts as a link to the proprietary site's play page.

My approach would be to have a single embedded player code, but dynamically inject the unique video ID from the selection. That is what I did for my site.

What you will need to do is have a database with fields for ( as example only ) `VIDEO_ID`, `VIDEO_LINK`, `PLAYER_TO_USE`, `OPTIONAL_URL` and so on depending on your needs. Depending on your videos, some selections may be blank as are not used for every video.

The hard part will be to grab only the unique video ID from the site's you are dealing with (you can have the user select the site they are uploading from so as to target your code).
With YouTube it is reasonably simple (i.e. *http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**HtPpaR3H8d8**&feature=g-user-lss*), but I have not looked at all the other sites to see how they index.

From there you can load the corresponding player with the chosen video ID on selection.
Not sure if this helps you at all, but I hope it does.